# Weird Logic Error C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Im not sure why this code only iterates once, i have tried making y>=0 and that just puts it into an infinite loop.The program is supposed to display the height of a projectile every 10th of a second. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
h = double.Parse(HBox.Text);
v = double.Parse(VBox.Text);
g = -32;
t = 0.1;
y = 0;


for (t = 0.1; y <= 0; t += 0.1)
 {
  y = (-1 / 2.0) * g * (Math.Pow(t, 2) + (v * t) + h);
  timeBox.Items.Add(y.ToString());

 }
```

Comment: the loops should stop when the projectile hits the ground(i.e. y<=0). the calculation i'm using is y(t)=−1/2gt^2+vt+h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code only iterates once because you have `<= 0` as your condition; which in terms of the projectile is saying "loop while it is below the ground". You were on the right track by having `>= 0` as the condition (projectile above the ground) except you have the formula wrong.

Integrating `gt + v` gives you `0.5gt^2 + vt`, notice the 0.5 is *positive*. You have it negative in your code (possibly due to the person who gave you the formula having acceleration due to gravity as positive). Switch that, or make gravity positive, and the conditional for the code to work:

```
for (t = 0.1; y >= 0; t += 0.1)
{
      y = 0.5 * g * Math.Pow(t, 2) + (v * t) + h);
      timeBox.Items.Add(y.ToString());   
}
```

You also misplaced some parenthesis; notice in the code above the `Math.Pow` is multiplied against gravity as it is supposed to be, you added it to `(v * t) + h` which is definitely not the same. If you don't want to print a negative height at the end, you need to check before outputting:

```
if (y > 0)
{
   timeBox.Items.Add(y.ToString());  
}
```

Comment: while this does take it out of the infinite loop, it now doesn't display any heights.

Comment: i've been using v=5 and h=10 as the user input which should make it land between 0.9 and 1.0 seconds

Comment: @EatMyBrick Note that I fixed an incorrect parenthesis in your equation (the `Math.Pow` result should be multiplied against gravity, not the result of the velocity and initial height addition). My code *as written* works on my computer.

Comment: is the last height -0.999999999996ish for you?

Comment: wouldn't that be after it hits the ground though?

Comment: @EatMyBrick Right, but the sequence is: check if height > 0; recalculate height; print new height; check again. Hence the negative value *must* be printed before the loop exits

Comment: is there a way to make it not be a negative number?

Comment: i'm not sure where this if statement should go, i tried a few different places and it's still negative

Comment: @EatMyBrick It goes exactly where I put it, surrounding the add to your `timeBox` (inside the `for` loop of course). Gotta learn to understand the *concept* of what I'm saying instead of just pasting the code

Comment: oh, i was completly adding the new if statment rather than incorperating the timebox.add into it, shouldn't the final positive result be between 0.9 and 1.0? I'm getting 1.54.

Comment: @EatMyBrick Not if the final velocity is < -1. I would guess your result is accurate (certainly matches mine)

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is iterating on i, but it's using y to check if it should run.

It's starting at 0, so it runs once, and then you have a negative number * g which is going to spit out a positive. y <= 0 is now false. This is also the same reason you get an infinite loop alternatively.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you should be checking the value of t (where your tracking time) until its reached 1 (1 second).

```
for (t = 0.1; t <= 1; t += 0.1)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: While this *could* solve the problem, it means he is only tracking the projectile for 1 second, not until it hits the ground.

Comment: Ahh I see I missunderstood